# Azure function key vault data not accessible from .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, environment-variables, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure function app .Net core solution from where, I am trying to access Azure key vault data, when the app is deployed. When in my local (development mode), I am accessing the key vault data from a local file (which is not deployed). Also, I want to have two more config files which will be deployed along with the app and will be used as per the environment where it is deployed.

I am stuck at one point..I am using three json files

1. local.settings.json (for local)
2. prod.settings.json (for prod)
3. dev.settings.json (for non prod)

### This is how I am configuring in my startup:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    `if(env=prod)
    {
    var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(applicationRootPath)
                            .AddJsonFile("prod.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                            .Build();
    }
    else 
    {
    var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(applicationRootPath)
                            .AddJsonFile("dev.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                            .Build();
    }
}
```

### This is how I am accessing the data in startup:

```
var fromKeyVault=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("keyVaultKey");
var fromJson=configBuilder.GetValue<string>("devKey");
```

both fromKeyVault and fromJson works perfectly in my local but when I try to deploy and test in non prod, fromKeyVault always returns null.
Do you see anything I can do to get a wayout of this issue.

The connection configuration has no issue between the .Net solution and Azure key vault.

I tried a few things like:

`configBuilder.GetValue<string>("keyVaultKey");` even this works well in my local but gives null in non prod.

### The expectation is:

1. The key vault values will be taken up from local.settings.json in my local env and when in prod/non prod,    it should be coming from Azure key vault.
2. In local, if any key is not present in local.settings.json then it should get it from dev.settings.json this behavior is also expected in environments.

Regards,
Debottam

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the key vault reference in the AppSettings:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#reference-syntax

When the function host starts up it loads the app settings and key vault secrets.

You will have to give your functionApp a managed identity so it can access the key vault.

In the past I have used two different methods:

1. Having a FunctionApp per environment. When you deploy your app via CI/CD, github actions etc the environment is dynamically generating the secrets and names required per environment.
2. Having a single FunctionApp but passing an environment as a query string or in the body of the payload sent with the request for an HTTP request.
   This means that you can load all app settings per environment but be specific of which secret is used within your app depending on the environment parameter.

Obviously there are pros and cons to each approach but having different settings per environment may not be the answer as appsettings are converted to `local.settings.json` on the host when it starts.